# Getting new value when ajax re-renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf-2, liferay

My code is working fine, but I am really not able to clearly understand it.

Can someone explain me please.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var portletNamespace = '#<portlet:namespace/>\\:formId\\:';
    $(portletNamespace + 'drpCategory').live('change', function () {
        alert('#{myController.simpleString}');
        $(portletNamespace + 'hiddenValue').ready(function () {
            alert($(portletNamespace + 'hiddenValue').val());
        });
    });
</script>

<h:inputText id="hiddenValue" value="#{myController.simpleString}" />

<h:selectOneMenu id="drpCategory">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Chọn thủ tục" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{myController.listCate}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.cateNane}"
    itemValue="#{item.cateId}" />
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="hiddenMap " listener="#{myController.changeCategory}"
    />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

after I change item in `drpCategory`, javascript alerts empty string first and then real value of `simpleString`. But if I remove the first alert code, the second will show me old value (before rendered by ajax)

For example, if I remove first alert code. First, `hiddenValue` is empty, change `drpCategory` value, `hiddenValue` changed to `'a'` but javascript alert empty, second time when I change `drpCategory` then `hiddenValue` is changed to `'b'` but it will still show `'a'`.

**edit:**
ah, I find out something, I had changed to:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var portletNamespace = '#<portlet:namespace/>\\:formId\\:';     
    $(portletNamespace+'drpCategory').live('change', function(){
        setTimeout('myFunc()', 500);    

    });

    function myFunc(){
            $(portletNamespace+'hiddenValue').ready(function(){
                alert($(portletNamespace+'hiddenValue').val());
            });
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your scenario right..

Change your

```
<f:ajax event="valueChange" render="hiddenMap " listener="#{myController.changeCategory}"
/>
```

into

```
<f:ajax onevent="callThisMethodAfterValueIsUpdated" event="valueChange" render="hiddenMap " listener="#{myController.changeCategory}"
/>
```

and in your js add this

```
var portletNamespace = '#<portlet:namespace/>\\:formId\\:'; 
function callThisMethodAfterValueIsUpdated(data) {
    if (data.status === 'success') {
        alert($(portletNamespace+'hiddenValue').val());
    }
}
```

relying on `setTimeout` is wrong cause it may vary from time to time server/traffic...

Comment: ak :D thank you very very much, i had spent alot of time to find solution

Comment: hmm, I use jQuery to add text to a <span> but when validation fail I loss the text, do you have any way to restore the text after validation fail :-?

Comment: well... you can always set it again using `onevent` of `f:ajax` that is being triggered by that button that calls the validation upon your field... but I think you better change your logic instead of finding workarounds...

Comment: Actually, I want somthing like:
When i type on an input text, using jQuery to bind keyup event and set that text for a span. Just for view layer and I'm not need it after form submit, but this span text disappear after first validation fail( strange thing is at second times validation fail it still there ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539544/restore-text-value-after-validtion-fail new question here ^^, and thank you again