# Restore text value after validation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsf-2, form-submit

I am using jQuery to bind a keyup event of an inputText, so that the value of it will be set to the span text.

```
<h:form id="formId">
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var portletNamespace = '#<portlet:namespace/>\\:formId\\:';             
        $(portletNamespace+'txtSimpleText').live('keyup',function(){    
             $(portletNamespace+'spanText').text($(portletNamespace+'txtSimpleText').val());    
        }); 
     });    
    </script>

    <h:inputText id="txtSimpleText" value=""/>
    <h:inputText required="true" value=""/>
    <h:outputText id="spanText"></h:outputText >
    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{myController.someAction}" value="do somthing"/>
</h:form>
```

It works fine, but at the first validation fail I lose my spanText text! This only happens the first time; at the second validation fail the spanText text is still there.
I only need it in the view layer, and have no need to use it after the form is submitted.
Please show me how to restore my spanText after validation fail!

PS: There is a reason I cannot use Ajax to store and set the value for spanText.

Comment: Actually, I set spanText text, after h:ouputText render, so i dont use .val() but use .text()

Comment: how about adding ` $(portletNamespace+'spanText').text($(portletNamespace+'txtSimpleText').val());` below defenition of `var portletNamespace...` ? that way upon ready the value will be copied too... isn't it ?

Comment: dont be mind about portletNamspace, this is only the way to get namespace in liferay, it return something like A3020

Comment: clearly code: $('#A3020\\:formId\\:'+'spanText').text(...)...

Comment: sorry i meant add ` $(portletNamespace+'spanText').text($(portletNamespace+'txtSimpleText').val());` below the defenition of `var portletNamespace` place console.log("some text"); to see that its being called after the button click

Comment: after form validation, it doesnt call to javascript again :-? I have try with alert, when load form it show message, but after validation it not show that msg again

Comment: you really better start using `f:ajax` ....